# PHP creating file with different user and group based on location of new file

Tags: php, file-permissions

I am attempting to create a file using PHP in a subfolder of my preferred folder.

I am using the following command:

```
file_put_contents("/preferred_folder/subfolder/test_A.txt", "test_A");
```

I receive the following error message:

```
Warning: file_put_contents(preferred_folder/subfolder/test_A.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /users/service/dummy_username/code.php on line ###.
```

I checked permissions of /preferred_folder/subfolder/ using the following command via PuTTY, where I am logged in as "dummy_username", and I receive the following response:

```
$ ls -l /preferred_folder/
drwxrwxr-x   7 1234567 1000001   120 Apr 30 13:35 subfolder
```

Write permissions for "other users" is not enabled, which is intended.  On the other hand, I don't recognize this user or the group so I checked:

```
$ groups 1000001
groups: 1000001: No such user
```

Also, "getent passwds 1234567" doesn't return any value (and it does successfully for "dummy_username").  Here's where it gets strange; I tried creating a file in two other locations as a sanity check: the first has write permissions for "other users" and the second is where my script has been creating files successfully for the past few years.

```
file_put_contents("/preferred_folder/test_B.txt", "test_B");
file_put_contents("/users/service/dummy_username/test_C.txt", "test_C");
```

In these cases, both files are successfully created, but the user and group of the files differs as such:

```
$ ls -l /preferred_folder/test_B.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 ABCDEFG root 5 Aug 30 08:39 /preferred_folder/test_B.txt

$ ls -l /users/service/dummy_username/test_C.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 dummy_username dummy_group 5 Aug 30 08:39 test_C.txt
```

I'm left with a few questions:

1) Why is the user and group for files created from this script different based only on file location ?  I expect that they would both be owned by "dummy_username".

2) What/who is the user "ABCDEFG"?  I've verified that the "root" group doesn't explicitly contain such a user.

3) What/who is the group "1000001" and why is the user "1234567" not known to be a part of that group either ?

4) Finally, aside from chmod 777'ing the entire preferred_folder and its many levels of subfolders, is there an appropriate and suggested means of granting specific permissions to my "dummy_username" for the intended file creation ?

Thanks in advance for any help.  Long-time visitor; third-time poster.

Answer (score 1):

The reasons why you're getting permission denied is because the user running PHP on the web server does not have permissions to write to that directory.

In many nginx/apache configurations web servers are set up to allow the user `www-data` access to `/var/www/html`. Your web application's root directory.

Writing outside of this directory will result in permissions errors.

There's very few reasons for PHP to have access to directories outside of `/var/www/html` unless you're writing scripts intended for the terminal.

If you're running PHP at the terminal, you can `sudo`, or create a user that has permissions to read/write from that directory and the run the script with that user.

Comment: Thanks for your response, @BugHunterUK.  I would like to grant permissions specifically to "dummy_username" by adding this user to the group that owns "/preferred_folder/subfolder" (i.e.- "1000001").  As mentioned, dummy_username can create files in preferred_folder albeit with a strange user/group. How would I know which username is appropriate to add to the group 1000001 ?  Moreover, can you provide any insight into why the user/group that owns the newly created file in preferred_folder is different than in /users/service/dummy_username/ ?  Where can I find and change such settings?  Thanks!

Comment: Update: I just found out about [ACLs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115631/getting-new-files-to-inherit-group-permissions-on-linux), which explains how file ownership is designated.